# Template of DocumentLibrary does not show up

Tags: document-library, list-template

i have created a template of a document library on site A. After that I downloaded it (it's an stp file) and uploaded it into the list template gallery at site B.

Now my problem: The new template does not show up in the "Create" dialog. Other templates does. Do you have any clues?

Edit:
I'm using Sharepoint Enterprise 2010

Comment: You are using MOSS 2007? Or WSS?

Comment: By other templates, you mean other custom templates or all te standard templates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the following post, which is similar. The original poster suggests the issue was caused by "language incompatiblity", which might help you.

You need to expand all of the comments relating to my answer to see the full trail.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8835774/sharepoint-imported-list-template-are-not-shown-when-creating-new-list-from-it/8835885#8835885

Answer (score 1):

Activate Team Collaboration Lists Feature from Site Actions --> Site Actions Manage site features on the publishing site.